# Nightwatchjs elementIdText function in a loop

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, nightwatch.js

I have difficulties to return text from **multiple IDs**, using [elementIdText](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#elementIdText) function in [Nightwatchjs](http://nightwatchjs.org/), it mights come from **asynchronous** feature.

I'm getting an **array of Web Element IDs** and trying to **make an array of the text** that they contain.

I did this, because the original [getText](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#getText) function doesn't iterate through all elements but only the first occurrence.

My common functions:

```
module.exports = {
  'ChildOf' : function(browser, path, callback) {
    browser
    .elements('css selector', path, function(elements) {
      var array = [];
      elements.value.forEach( function(element) {
        array.push(element.ELEMENT);
      })
      //console.log(array); out: Final array filled; Works great
      callback(array);
    })
  },

  'getText' : function(browser, elements, callback) {
    var array = [];
    elements.forEach( function(element) {
      browser.elementIdText(element, function(result) {
        array.push(result.value);
        //console.log(array); out: Multiple incremented arrays; Need the final array :\
      })
      //console.log(array); out: Multiple empty arrays; Doesn't work
    })
    //console.log(array); out: Single empty array; Doesn't work
    callback(array);
  }
]
```

My Call:

```
module.exports = {
  'myStep' : function(browser, expect) {
    common.ChildOf(browser, '.txt', function(elements) {
      common.getText(browser, elements, function(result) {
        //browser.verify.equal(result, expect)
      })
    })
  }
};
```

I need to get a full filled array of strings comming from my custom getText function that I can compare to another array (data driven tests), any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using promise (Q), 4 lines added, thanks to [this](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/529) Nightwatchjs Github issue.